# relation between covariant and contravariant vectors

Tags: matrices, tensors, kronecker-delta

The change from covariant to contravariant or vice-versa is defined as 
$$v_{i}=g_{ij}v^j$$
The component of a dyad, gij in general is given by
$${g}_{ij} = \vec{e}^i . \vec{e}^j$$ here
$$e⃗^ i\,\text{ and }\, e⃗^ j $$ Contravariant basis vectors
a similar statement can be defined for a covariant basis vector

Why has the superscript of the contravariant basis replaced by the subscript for the dyad component, gij.Is  it just a notation..as  $$\vec{e}^i . \vec{e}^j$$ is just scalar product of two vectors which is just a scalar, hence its neither contravariant or covariant...or am I missing something

This is a repost of a part of another post...I have the same question so I am asking again.[image]

Comment: it should be $g_{ij}=e_i\cdot e_j$ for a contravariant base vectors and $g^{ij}=e^i\cdot e^j$ for covectors

Comment: i have added a picture...and its stated the opposite in the book

Comment: The book does not seem to be employing the index balance of Einstein's convention properly. If $(V,g)$ is an Euclidean space with basis $(e_i)$ and dual basis $(e^i)$, then $g = g_{ij}e^i\otimes e^j$ where $g_{ij}=g(e_i,e_j)$. This matrix in non-singular, and so we obtain an inner product $g^*$ in $V^*$, by $g^* = g^{ij}e_i\otimes e_j$, where $g^{ij}=g^*(e^i,e^j)$ defines the inverse matrix of $(g_{ij})$. [My short notes](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/tensors.pdf) on tensors might be helpful.

Comment: in some books we also learn what we shouldn't be doing